# Is it possible to ignore/change the url from PostBackUrl in asp.Button from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET webforms and I'm wondering if it is possible to change/ignore the PostBackUrl so it won't change pages.

My button:

```html
<asp:Button ID="continuebtn" OnClick="Continuebtn_Click" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/client/profile.aspx" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" Text="Continue"/>
```

And the OnClick function is:

```cs
protected void Continuebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code
    if(condition == false)
       //change the url from PostBackUrl so it won't change pages
    else
       //keep the current Url  
}
```

I've tried :

```cs
continuebtn.PostBackUrl = "";

continuebtn.Attributes["PostBackUrl"] = "return false";

continuebtn.Attributes.Remove("OnClick");
continuebtn.Attributes.Add("OnClick","return false");

continuebtn.OnClientClick = "return false;";

add return; to if
```

I tried to remove the PostBackUrl from the button and add it from the code behind with `continuebtn.PostBackUrl = "~/client/profile.aspx"` but it didn't work either.

Comment: What does your rendered HTML show after `continuebtn.PostBackUrl = "~/client/profile.aspx";`?

Comment: It doens't render nothing new until the postback, after the postback the rendered onclick is: ```onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("continuebtn", "", false, "", "../client/profile.aspx", false, false))"```

Comment: You can change the postback url - but NOT in its own button click event!! When you click on that button - the postback url WILL occur - the code behind event also runs - but they both will and are pending to run. So you can't change the postback url for the SAME button click in the same event code stub. You can certainly say have two buttons. In button1 code behind just set button2.PostbackUrl = "" or any page you want. However, you can't of course modify the same button in the the code behind click event, since it already had a post-back url set and changing after button click is too late.

Comment: So can I use button1 as a "modifier " for button2 and click button2 using a js function?

Comment: Yes, that should work - So as long as the js changes the post-back URL before the js code does a "click" on that button - you should be ok. I think that should work and not need a round trip. On the other hand, why not then put the logic in button2 in code behind and figure out if you want to navigate some place else anyway? As noted, their is a BIG difference using code behind + response.redirect as compared to post-back URL - HUGE and VERY big difference occurs. I explain this difference below in my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two big reasons to use post-back URL in place of say using a code behind click event and say then response.Redirect("some web page").

First up, post-back url passes the previous page!!!!!

So, if you have say a text box and a button like this: (or evne a grid view)

[image]

Now you can use code behind to jump to the next page, or you can use/set/have post-back url set.

If you use post-back URL. Then you don't need to write a code behind stub, and you ALSO get use of previous page in the next page on-load event (you ONLY can pick up previous page in load - first time).

eg:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack == false)
{
    TextBox tbox;
    tbox = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");

    Debug.Print("Text box = " + tbox.Text);
    TextBox1.Text = s;
    }
}
}
```

so post-back url = a great way to pass/get at/use the previous page values with find control. Now if you not needing to do this, then you probably should not use post-back URL, since you are bulking up the payload for the next page (it will contain the current page, and you have as noted use of "previous page". However, it is a fantastic way to avoid parameters and/or cluttering up session() just to pass a bunch of values. Just use post-back URL and then like "magic" then previous page can be used. if you don't use post-back URL then previous page is null and not valid.

And if you place two buttons on the page? Can you set postback url? Sure you can set that control, text box or do anything you like - but do keep in mind that the code behind is running AFTER a post-back, and it will of course be too late to change a button that CAUSED the post back.

So, you can certainly do this in button2 click even to change button1:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Button1.PostBackUrl = "";
}
```

So in above, button3 click event and code behind wiped out the post-back URL of button one. Or we can of course set the url to anything we want.

Now, the code behind is done, page is rendered and THEN sent back down to the browser with the above change. If user hits button1, then no postback url exists - we blew it out with the above code.

However, in the SAME button event? no, it is too late to change or modify the post-back.

In that case, and if you need "conditional" jump? Then  you need to delete and remove the post-back url, and simply put the logic you need to determine the ya, or nay jump based on the code behind for that click event.

HOWEVER - and a BIG WHOPPER however? If you JUST use a response.Redirect("some web page") in that code behind, then you DROPPIGN THE MAIN reason as to why the  developer used post-back URL in the first place. That main, big, huge, large reason is that post-back URL gives the next page in line FULL USE of the previous page values with "previous page". If you do NOT use post-back URL, then you can't use previous page to pass all those values and inspect and get and grab control values from the previous page.

So what if  you really did need the "abilities" that post-back URL provides (that ability of course is "previous" page in the next page load!

In that case, then you have to use Server.Transfer() in that code stub to get use of previous page in the next page that loads.

So, regardless:

You can't change post-back URL in the same button code event - it is too late.

If you are going to then put the logic in the code event? Then be VERY VERY aware that if you use a response.Redirect("some web page"), then you may VERY well be breaking the functionally of why in the first place the developer used post-back url (to have use of "previous page".

Your suggested idea to modify client side the post-back url in one button click, and then do a js "click" of that button you just changed the post-back url should also work (good idea!!!).

But, I would thing that just using a code behind stub in the click event, and then the code can choose to navagate or jump to the next page based on that code? Right?

However, if you do that, then you will break the "features" of post-back URL in pasing page prevous.

In that case? Then you need to use a server.Transfer("to next web page") in place of response.Redirect("to next web page), since a server.Transfer will give you use of "page previous" in the next page load event JUST LIKE post-back URL does!

Of course with a server.Transfer, you will note that the web page URL does not change or update - and this is a fall out of having to do this. (and may, or may not matter to you).

Comment: Excellent! server-transfer allows the code behind stub to check things, make a decision and if to next page navigation IS wanted and you ALSO need previous page? Then server.transfer() allows this without needing post-back URL. I find this a fantastic way to say jump from a grid view with a button. You use server transfer, and thus have full use of the grid values in the next page  (previous page). And I find it really interesting that you WERE in fact using post-back URL for a good reason and the correct reason and the right reason. However, server.transfer() also gets page previous to work